# Simple Freelock collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, lock-free

I wrote simple lock-free collection class for saving items from multithreading code. I did it just for fun and experience. Can you check my code for potentially problems please?

```
    public class InputBox<T>
    {
        private BoxItem<T> _current;

        public InputBox()
        {
            _current = null;
        }

        public void Add(T value)
        {
            var nextItem = new BoxItem<T>(value);
            BoxItem<T> initialItem = null;
            do
            {
                initialItem = _current;
                nextItem.Next = _current;
            } while (initialItem != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _current,
                                                                nextItem,
                                                                initialItem));
        }

        public bool TryAdd(T value)
        {
            var initialItem = _current;
            return initialItem ==
                   Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _current, 
                                               new BoxItem<T>(value, _current), 
                                               initialItem);
        }

        public BoxResultCollection<T> TakeAll()
        {
            return new BoxResultCollection<T>(_current);
        }
    }

    internal sealed class BoxItem<T>
    {
        private readonly T _value;
        private BoxItem<T> _next;

        internal BoxItem(T value)
            :this(value, null)
        {
            // empty
        }

        internal BoxItem(T value, BoxItem<T> next)
        {
            _value = value;
            _next = next;
        }

        internal T Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }

        internal BoxItem<T> Next
        {
            get { return _next; }
            set { _next = value; }
        }
    }

    public class BoxResultCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly BoxItem<T> _root;

        internal BoxResultCollection(BoxItem<T> root)
        {
            _root = root;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var current = _root;

            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current.Value;
                current = current.Next;
            }

            yield break;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool IsEmpty
        {
            get { return _root == null; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool TryAdd(T value)
```

A method that intentionally doesn't work when there is contention? I don't see how would that be ever useful.

```
internal BoxItem<T> Next
{
    get { return _next; }
    set { _next = value; }
}
```

You could have used an autoproperty here.

```
yield break;
```

Adding `yield break;` at the end of iterator method is the same as adding `return;` at te end of a normal `void` method: the method would work exactly the same without it.

```
public IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable()
```

I don't see how would this method be useful. Especially since there already is [`AsEnumerable()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: _This won't work correctly if _current changes between the two assignments. The same issue is also in TryAdd(). A method that intentionally doesn't work when there is contention? I don't see how would that be ever useful._ <br/> Are you sure? I tried change *_current* between the two assignments, but it is still work correctly. Can you show example that broke my code?

Comment: @artem I think you're right, I removed that part from my answer.